# Webhooks: GCP and Github

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, console, cloud

Since Github changed their authentication methods to only accept Personal Access Tokens I've had some trouble with getting my GCP Build Trigger to run when I push to the main branch of my repo.

Does anyone know how I can re-authenticate, or change the password that's being used to connect GCP to Github?

On GCP I have tried reconnecting to the repo, 'forgetting' the repo and then reconnecting, I'm not incredibly clued up on this platform, I've only been using it for a few weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"token" would be used for HTTPS URL.

The official [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/access-private-github-repos) uses SSH URLs, which does not need tokens (but SSH keys): that would be one alternative.

Comment: Thank you, should've just read the docs lol